# Control the :after of a div when hover on another element

Tags: css

I want to control after of `box2` when hovering on `box1`.
I test this code but it didn't work.so...whats the problem?

```
.box1:hover .box2:after{SOME CSS}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Can you provide your html? Where is box2 in relation to box1?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box1 , .box2 , .box2:after{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.box2:after {
 content: 'Box2:after';
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 left: 200px;
 top: -30px;
}

.box1:hover ~ .box2:after {
 background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">BOX 1:hover my</div>
<div class="box2">Box 2</div>
```